# how to use interface with singleton class

Tags: c#

As I go through the differences between Singleton Vs Static class, I came across one point that we can inherit an interface in singleton class and can call singleton through interface for multiple implementation.

I would like some code demonstration with good example, how object orientation can achieve through singleton and not through static.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post some example in "pseudocode" ?

Comment: what you already tried?

Comment: how about searching for one in google or try to create one yourself

Comment: interfaces cant have statics, therefor you cant implement an interface in a static class, why exactly do you need an example? also a static class would use ram even if unused, while singleton will only use ram if actually called

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/15476/10155

Comment: "call singleton through interface for multiple implementation" is an oxymoron - by definition if it is a singleton there is only one instance.

Comment: There can be multiple singleton implementations conforming to an interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's hard to tell what exactly you are referring to, one pattern you might be referring to is the [Multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern), where you manage a map of named instances as key-value pairs.

That's basically a factory, but each instance is only created once:

I've modified the [Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern#C.23) a bit to show that you can even derive from a singleton class, as long as your concrete implementations are private and within the original class:

```
class FooMultiton
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<object, FooMultiton> _instances =
        new Dictionary<object, FooMultiton>();

    // this is the classic good old singleton trick (prevent direct instantiation)
    private FooMultiton()
    { }

    // you can also have private concrete implementations, 
    // invisible to the outside world
    private class ConcreteFooMultitonOne : FooMultiton
    { }

    public static FooMultiton GetInstance(object key)
    {
        lock (_instances) 
        {   
            FooMultiton instance;

            // if it doesn't exist, create it and store it
            if (!_instances.TryGetValue(key, out instance))
            {
                // at this point, you can create a derived class instance
                instance = new ConcreteFooMultitonOne();
                _instances.Add(key, instance);
            }

            // always return the same ("singleton") instance for this key
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, generally, if a singleton is not a static class, it can implement any interface you want. The only thing that a singleton pattern prevents is instantiation of multiple instances of a singleton class, but that doesn't mean you cannot completely replace the implementation with something else.

For example, if you have a singleton which is not a static class:

```
interface ICanTalk
{
    string Talk();
}

class Singleton : ICanTalk
{
    private Singleton() { }

    private static readonly Singleton _instance = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton Instance
    { get { return _instance; } }

    public string Talk()
    { return "this is a singleton"; }
}
```

You can also have a number of different implementations:

```
class OtherInstance : ICanTalk
{
    public string Talk()
    { return "this is something else"; }
}
```

Then you are free to choose any implementation you want, but get only a single instance of the `Singleton` class:

```
ICanTalk item;

item = Singleton.Instance;
item = new OtherInstance();
item = new YetAnotherInstance();
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [nkr1pr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1497012/2004810)

Every class can implement an interface, and a Singleton is just a "normal" class that makes sure that only one instance of it exists at any point in time apart from the other business logic it may implement. This also means that a Singleton has at least 2 responsibities and this is not good OO design as classes should only have 1 responsibility and make sure they are good at that responsibility, but that is another discussion.

Something like:

```
public interface MyInterface 
{
}
```

And

```
public class MySingleton:MyInterface
{
  private static MyInterface instance = new MySingleton();

  private MySingleton() 
  {
  } 

  public static MyInterface getInstance()
  {
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: In C#, a static class cannot implement an interface.

Comment: But that's not a static class.  Static class = public static class MySingleton {}

Comment: @OneManCrew: Chris was probably referring to your *every class can implement an interface* statement, which does not hold for static classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but singleton classes can implement interfaces.
singleton class does not mean static class, one of the method to create a singleton instance is
to make use of static members.

```
public class MyInterfaceImplementation : IMyInterface
{

    private static MyInterfaceImplementation instance;
    private static readonly object lockObj = new object();

    private MyInterfaceImplementation() { }  //private .ctor

    public static MyInterfaceImplementation Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (lockObj)
                {
                    instance = new MyInterfaceImplementation();
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void MyInterfaceMethod()
    {
        //Implement here
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do a second `if (instance == null)` inside the lock to make sure you didn't have two threads arrive at the `lock` at the same time. Otherwise you might still produce multiple instances of the singleton.

Comment: On MSDN, see [lock Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).